# The addons on my Garry's Mod server

Tags: hosting, garrys-mod, steamcmd

When I create a server by SteamCMD, should I see my addons I subscribed? just like when I play an offline server? or my addons aren't active in the dedicated server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your addons are not active. You have to set up an addon collection for your server and set it so that it'll download and make people who connect use them. [How you can set that up can be found here.](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Workshop_for_Dedicated_Servers)

It basically is, [get an apikey](https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey), [create an addon collection and note down the collection's id](https://steamcommunity.com/workshop/browse/?appid=4000&section=collections) and launch with `+host_workshop_collection WORKSHOPID -authkey YOURKEYGOESHERE`

Comment: Thanks! is that include playmodels and tools?

Comment: @deadmanwalking78 that includes EVERYTHING. It'll be like vanilla gmod if you don't set it up- even TF2 etc. props won't show up.

Comment: Thanks<3 but I do that for every single addon? or I can do it once for all my subscribed addons?

Comment: @deadmanwalking78 you have to put your subbed addons to a collection, and do it just for that. You can use one by other people too though.